# Request/Route Filter in Kentico 7

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, content-management-system, kentico

Is there a way to perform a filter within Kentico 7 before pages/content are served?

My scenario is I need to validate a query string parameter, and if it's not valid, the client is redirected to another page. I know this can be easily done via JavaScript but turning off JS in your browser can bypass that easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are events in CMSPages_PortalTemplate and it`s base classes like:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    protected override void OnError(EventArgs e);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Init event handler.
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Load event handler.
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     PreInit event handler.
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     PreRender event handler.
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Unload event handler.
    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e);
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Render event handler.
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer);
    .
    .
    .
```

But I am not sure and I doubt it`s not best practice. Maybe you could describe more your problem and what kind of querystring, why and where you want to validate.

Comment: There is just a value that needs to be validated and it is taken from the query string. If the validation is correct, the page loads normally, if not, the user is redirected. That is all there is.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm in your place I'll create a simple web parts like "RandomRedirection". Here is the path of the file of this web parts in the version 8 `~/CMSWebParts/General/RandomRedirection.ascx.cs`. You can test the query string parameter in your web parts code and make the redirection according to.

Here is an example of code inspired from RandomREdirection web parts (sorry, I don't have version 7 installed locally so my code is not tested in this version but with version 8)

```
using System;

using CMS.Helpers;
using CMS.PortalControls;
using CMS.PortalEngine;

public partial class CMSWebParts_General_RandomRedirection : CMSAbstractWebPart
{
    #region Webpart properties

    /// <summary>
    /// URL to redirect if the query value is not correct.
    /// </summary>
    public string RedirectionURL
    {
        get
        {
            return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("RedirectionURL"), "");
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue("RedirectionURL", value);
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Webpart methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Content loaded event handler.
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnContentLoaded()
    {
        base.OnContentLoaded();
        SetupControl();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the control properties.
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetupControl()
    {
        if (!StopProcessing)
        {
            if ((RedirectionURL.Trim().Length > 0) &&
                PortalContext.ViewMode.IsLiveSite())
            {
                string newURL = URLHelper.ResolveUrl(RedirectionURL.Trim());
                if ((RequestContext.CurrentURL != newURL) &&
                    (URLHelper.GetAbsoluteUrl(RequestContext.CurrentURL) != newURL))
                {
                    var value = QueryHelper.GetString("queryName", String.Empty);
                    //Test value of your query parameter
                    if (!value.Equals("queryValue"))
                    {
                        newURL = URLHelper.RemoveParameterFromUrl(newURL, "queryName");
                        URLHelper.ResponseRedirect(newURL);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Reloads the control data.
    /// </summary>
    public override void ReloadData()
    {
        base.ReloadData();
        SetupControl();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Put your web parts in top zone of your master page and here you go.

Hope this helps!